# Trigger LinkClicked when button is pressed

Tags: navigation, elm, elm-ui

I'm building an Elm application and am trying to add navigation [as per the manual](https://guide.elm-lang.org/webapps/navigation.html).

I've added the required handling of `LinkClicked` and `UrlChanged` and they work fine for `href`, but they don't work for buttons that lead to different pages.

For example, in my search page:

```
    ...
    , Input.button [ centerX ] -- This doesn't trigger a navigation message
        { onPress = Just StartSearch
        , label = text "Search"
        }
    , Element.link []  -- This triggers a navigation message
        { label = text "Search"
        , url = "/search"
        }
    ...
```

How do I apply navigation changes when buttons are clicked?

Comment: Why not put whatever navigation change you want to happen in the 'StartSearch' branch of the case in your 'update' function?

Comment: @5ndG according to the manual, the linkclicked / urlchanged messages result in a command. Am I able to perform both that command and the command required for starting my search as a result of that single message?

Comment: Yes, you can [batch](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Platform-Cmd#batch) commands.